# Visual Studio add item to VSIX project, can't find file key.snk

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was getting started with how to write an extension for Visual Studio. I created a VSIX project from built-in template and try to add an item to the project but an error message appear stating that it can't find "key.snk" file within the project folder [Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bbna.png), and the add item window appear again. The new items are still created but I get "No resource file set the resource manager" error on build. How to resolve this ?

Comment: Everything you add to a VSIX needs to be strong-named. Make sure your class library project is.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I didn't come across the "strong-named" stuff on tutorials I found